# InconsistentTableError rows different from columns error of astropy Table.read()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, astropy

I'm triying to read a **.txt** file with astropy's `Table.read()` as:

> ```
> data = Table.read('BD_FONDECYT_1120715Py(03-2019).txt', format='ascii', guess=False)
> ```

I added `guess=False` because without it the error was less clear.

I'm working with a database and always use scripts to read it. Now, I added some new data and the code shows this error:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
data = Table.read('BD_FONDECYT_1120715Py(03-2019).txt', format='ascii', guess=False)                                                                  
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\astropy\table\table.py", line 2550, in read 
out = io_registry.read(cls, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\registry.py", line 517, in read
data = reader(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\connect.py", line 20, in read_asciitable
return read(filename, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\ui.py", line 390, in read
dat = fast_reader_rdr.read(table)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\astropy\io\ascii\fastbasic.py", line 128, in read
data, comments = self.engine.read(try_int, try_float, try_string)
File "astropy\io\ascii\cparser.pyx", line 385, in astropy.io.ascii.cparser.CParser.read astropy.io.ascii.core.InconsistentTableError: Number of header columns (22) inconsistent with data columns in data line 0'
```

I looked every where, changed every value on the table (to float and 2 decimal), checked the new values if they have a blank space or something like it, but can't figure out what's happening. I even changed Python version from 2.7 to 3.7 and reinstalled `astropy` and `numpy`.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like it might be because, when you added new data and changed the number of columns, you didn't also add a field/column name to the first row of the file.

Comment: Hi martineau, I added new data but in the same columns that I had, didn't created a new set of columns

Comment: This appears to be an issue with your input file, given the error message. Could you list the first few lines of that file?

Comment: Solved! I saved the table like a csv, then opened it and saved it as .txt and worked but still don't know what was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is occurring because your data table has varying numbers of columns, possibly because of a missing data value. AstroPy tries to guess where the header and the data parts of the table (which you can override with `header_start=` and `data_start=` in the call to `astropy.io.ascii.read()`, see [method definition](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.io.ascii.read.html#astropy.io.ascii.read) in the docs). The header is used to define the number of columns it's expecting to read from the table; if this changes midway through your data, you will get the `InconsistentTableError`

For example if you have a table that looks like this (with hash as the comment/header delimiter):

```
# X Y Z
1 2 3
3 4 5
6   9
```

then it will fail on row 3 as there are now 2 columns not 3. You need to ensure whatever produces the table fills in 'something' for bad/missing data and/or that this can't be mistaken for the separators between columns (or override this in the call). This may be why it "appeared to work" after converting to CSV; CSV makes a distinction between common blank values (spaces) and the column separators (commas) that may not have been in the original table data, preventing this confusion for the code between a missing value and the gaps between columns.